# Codeigniter importing data using excel file

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to  import data via excel sheet into database with codeigniter application.I am using phpexcel. However the code is right but i am getting an error which states:

> Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'joker' in 'field list'
>   INSERT INTO studentsaccount (joker) VALUES ('')
>   Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Nalanda_Library/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 691

however my code is as follows: for controller

```
public function studentaccountimport(){
        $this->load->model('Department');

        $file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        //load the excel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        //read file from path
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
        //get only the Cell Collection
        $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
        //extract to a PHP readable array format
        foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
            $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
            $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
            $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
            //header will/should be in row 1 only.
            if ($row == 1) {
                $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            } else {
                $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
                $this->Department->modeluploadation($data_value);

            }
        }
    }
```

for model:

```
public function modeluploadation($data){
    $this->db->insert('studentsaccount',$data);
    }
```

i am novice in codeigniter here so please help

Comment: And what's unclear to you?

Comment: @u_mulder it is giving me an error when i try to import data into database read the question first

Comment: I've read the question and the error. And it's pretty obvious, so I ask again - what is unclear to you?

Comment: Did You have that field joker in field list

Comment: @premi joker is just the data from excel sheet file sir...i just don't understand how to put the field name there!

Comment: 1. in excel put field names on top of column. 2. You need to specify column names in insert query...

Comment: @safinchacko that is what i am not getting how do i specify column name in insert query when i am using it via active records

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: put the field name in top of the excel sheet

Comment: what is the column name in database table?

Answer (score 0):

***You need to specify column names in insert query..***

try

```
if ($row == 1) {
                $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
            } else {
                $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;


            }

$data['header'] = $header;
$data['values'] = $arr_data;

 $this->Department->modeluploadation($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the reason for your problem is you need to pass an array of key=>value pairs as the parameter for insert().

I'm not sure why Safins answer has been marked down because he is right. So when you should set modeluploadation as:

```
public function modeluploadation($data){
        $this->db->insert('studentsaccount',array('field_name'=>$data_value));
}
```

Comment: now getting an error stating you must use set method to make an entry!